# What's the difference between none and null CipherAlgorithmType?

Tags: .net, ssl, encryption

The .net Framework SSL stream implementation has the property `CipherAlgorithm` with the type `CipherAlgorithmType`. This enumeration includes `None` and `Null`. What is the difference between this two values?

From the documentation I don't get the difference:

> `None`: No encryption algorithm is used.
>
> `Null`: No encryption is used with a Null cipher algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The 'CipherAlgorithmType' Type**

```
CipherAlgorithmType
```

**None: No encryption algorithm is used:**

When Type is set to 'None' then the plaintext will not use any encryption such as the example below. It will encrypt the data as normal with any other algorithm applied.

**Null: No encryption is used with a Null cipher algorithm.**

> A null cipher, also known as concealment cipher, is an ancient form of
>   encryption where the plaintext is mixed with a large amount of
>   non-cipher material.

In a null cipher, the plaintext is included within the ciphertext and one needs to discard certain characters in order to decrypt the message.